# App crashes, seemingly because of EditText to String to Double/Long conversion

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I need to input a few values into a Room database. To do so I need to convert whatever the user inputs to a Double and a Long. For some reason the app crashes every time I try to do this. I'm fairly certain that the issue is in the two variables marked with `//Need to fix`, because I tried initializing them to 0, and the app works fine after that. I am happy to provide any more info if it is needed. What might be the issue here?

This is the code:

```
    override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    var transacType = false
    var transacAmount = binding.amountInput.text.toString().toDouble()          //Need to fix
    var transacDate: Long = binding.pickedDate.text.toString().toLong()         //Need to fix
    var transacCategory: String = "N"
    val duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

    ...

    binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{
        if (transacCategory == "N" || transacCategory == "Pick a category…" && binding.spinner2.isVisible) {

            val text = "Please pick a category!"
            val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, duration)
            toast.show()
        } else if (transacAmount == 0.0) {

            val text = "Please input an amount!"
            val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, duration)
            toast.show()
        } else {

            val transaction = Transactions(0L, transacType, transacAmount, transacDate, transacCategory)
            transactionViewModel.insert(transaction)
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if it is necessary, but this is all the red stuff in the log that I do not know how to read:

```
2021-04-02 17:25:54.438 22619-22619/com.example.budgie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.budgie, PID: 22619
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.budgie/com.example.budgie.AddTransactionActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4789)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4832)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:190)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at com.example.budgie.AddTransactionActivity.onResume(AddTransactionActivity.kt:72)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1465)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4779)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4832) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:190) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:105) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

PS. I am aware that there are probably other problems in my code, but right now I am only trying to solve this one.

PSS. I'm fairly new, go easy on me will ya?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the answer, but just to explain how people know (so you can investigate mysteries too)...

The red text in the log is the stacktrace - it's printed when you get an exception (a kind of error) that crashes the app, and it shows which line it crashed on, the chain of methods that led up to it, and what caused the crash. So you get an idea of what was going on and where you need to look!

It's arranged in blocks, the first one starts with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity [...]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4789)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4832)
    ...
```

so your app crashed with a `RuntimeException` and the message it holds (the explanation basically) is "unable to resume activity". The next line says that exception was thrown at line 4789 of `ActivityThread.java`, in `performResumeActivity()`, and you got there from line 4832 of `handleResumeActivity()` in the same file, etc...

---

Sometimes that's useful, in this case that's all Android internal stuff you didn't write, so let's look at the next block, which is the exception that was thrown that made `performResumeActivity` give up and throw its exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText{64a283 VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f09004a app:id/amount_input}"
```

Same deal as before, but we don't need to look any deeper - we have all the info we need right here! This `NumberFormatException` caused the outer `RuntimeException` that crashed the app. `NumberFormatException`s usually show up when you try to read some text as a number, but it doesn't conform to a legit format - and it's telling you the input string that caused it, which definitely can't be read as a number!

If you look down the stacktrace in that block, you get to this bit:

```
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at com.example.budgie.AddTransactionActivity.onResume(AddTransactionActivity.kt:72)
```

which is telling you that the `parseDouble()` call that's throwing is being called at line 72 of `AddTransactionActivity`, which is basically pointing at where the problem is (or starts) in your own code. (It helps to scan down the trace until you spot `com.example.budgie` or whatever your package name is, so you can find where your actual code gets involved.)

So even if you don't know exactly why it's wrong, you know what to look at! And you know you're passing the wrong input string - it should be a number in the `TextView`, but it's some stuff instead. You might not recognise what all that stuff is, but hopefully you see "`TextView`" in there, and realise that the `TextView` itself is somehow getting involved, and you're not getting the text contents. And then you can go look into that, see if you're doing it right...

Don't worry, the `textView.text` thing trips me up all the time too. And yeah the input string is printed in the first line of the stacktrace (the `RuntimeException` is printing the message of its cause) but I wanted to show that you can look at each block separately, and read the trace to find out where a thing happened exactly

Hope that helps you or someone else!

Comment: Thank you so much! It did help me understand how to find the problem and to identify it, and after adding the `.text` to the initial declaration of those variables the stacktrace changed. Now it says `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`. At least I'm getting somewhere!

Comment: Well hopefully that one's more obvious ;) Kotlin has a bunch of ``...OrNull`` functions, like ``toDoubleOrNull``, which produce a ``null`` value instead of throwing an exception, so you can deal with errors that way. Your broader problem here is that you start up with no data in the input boxes, so you need to decide how to handle that situation. I'd recommend some kind of validator function, checking that the user's entered stuff that you can actually use, before you try to do anything with it! That way you're handling startup and also future shenanigans

Answer (score 1):

`binding.amountInput` is type of EditText and you are trying to do toString() on EditText not the text inside the edittext. Since it is object type, toString just prints its type which is `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` then trying to cast this string into number and that causes exception. What you need to do is:
`var transacAmount = binding.amountInput.text.toString().toDouble()`

Comment: Okay, so I fixed that part of the code but for some reason it is still crashing when the screen the EditText is on is supposed to open. Nevertheless, thank you for helping out.